# find data daily weekly and monthly using date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am new in node js i need to find data daily, 
weekly and monthly but i don't know how to do this? 
currently i am finding today data . also need to find current week data and current month data. 
i don't have idea how to do this, can you please help.

```
exports.getData = function(req,res)
{
getMyData().then(function(data){
    res.status(200).json({
        msg:'true',
        data: data
    });
}).catch(function(err){
    res.status(401).json({
        msg:'Not Logged In',
        error: err
    });
});
function getMyData(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
        if (!token)
        return reject({'msg':'No Token'});
        jwt.verify(token,config.secret,function(err,decode){

            if(err)
            {
                reject({'msg':'Failed to authenticate token.'});
            } 
            else{

                var start = new Date();
                start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
                var end = new Date();
                end.setHours(23,59,59,999);

                Data.find({userId: decode.id,created: {$gte: start, $lt: end}},function(err,data){
                    if(err){
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resolve(data);
                    }
                });
            } 
        });
    });
  }
}
```

here is my schema

```
var DataSchema = new Schema({
userId: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Kindly enter your Report'
},data: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Kindly enter your Report'
},
created:{
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now
}
});
```

Comment: are you getting today's data successfully ?

Comment: @UsmanRana Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call find query based on different conditions from node.js.

```
async function getMyData() {
    var token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
    if (!token)
        throw {
            'msg': 'No Token'
        };
    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function (err, decode) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            let today = new Date();
            today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
            let first = today.getDate() - today.getDay();
            let last = first + 6;
            let firstday = new Date(today.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
            let lastday = new Date(today.setDate(last)).toUTCString();
            let firstDayMonth = new Date(today.setDate(1));
            let lastDayMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0)
            lastDayMonth.setHours(23, 59, 59, 0);
            today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

            return await Promise.all([
                Data.find({
                    userId: decode.id,
                    created: {
                        $gte: today
                    }
                }).exec(),
                Data.find({
                    userId: decode.id,
                    created: {
                        $gte: firstday,
                        $lte: lastday
                    }
                }).exec(),
                Data.find({
                    userId: decode.id,
                    created: {
                        $gte: firstDayMonth,
                        $lte: lastDayMonth
                    }
                }).exec()
            ]);
        }
    });
}
```

**MongoDB Aggregate query** : only problem I'm seeing is $cond else block returns "". That you can handle in node js.

```
var today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var first = today.getDate() - today.getDay();
var firstDayWeek = new Date(today.setDate(first));
var lastDayWeek = new Date(today.setDate(first + 6));
var firstDayMonth = new Date(today.setDate(1));
var lastDayMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0)
lastDayWeek.setHours(23, 59, 59, 0);
lastDayMonth.setHours(23, 59, 59, 0);
today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

db.getCollection('TEST').aggregate([{
        $match: {
            userId: decode.id
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            "_id": "",
            "today": {
                $push: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $gte: ["$created", new Date(today)]
                        },
                        then: "$$ROOT",
                        else: ''
                    }
                }
            },
            "week": {
                $push: {
                    $cond: [{
                            $and: [{
                                    $gte: ["$created", new Date(firstDayWeek)]
                                },
                                {
                                    $lte: ["$created", new Date(lastDayWeek)]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "$$ROOT",
                        ''
                    ]
                }
            },
            "month": {
                $push: {
                    $cond: [{
                            $and: [{
                                    $gte: ["$created", new Date(firstDayMonth)]
                                },
                                {
                                    $lte: ["$created", new Date(lastDayMonth)]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "$$ROOT",
                        ''
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }])
    //If you want to filter in mongo query
    .forEach(function (data) {
        data.today = data.today.filter(e => e != "")
        data.week = data.week.filter(e => e != "")
        print(data);
    })
```

**Output**

```
{
    "_id": "",
    "today": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("5aaa2605d52a86d42a362479"),
            "created": ISODate("2018-03-15T07:51:33.014Z")
        }
    ],
    "week": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("5aaa2605d52a86d42a362479"),
            "created": ISODate("2018-03-15T07:51:33.014Z")
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5aaa2606d52a86d42a36247a"),
            "created": ISODate("2018-03-13T07:51:34.702Z")
        }
    ],
    "month": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("5aaa2605d52a86d42a362479"),
            "created": ISODate("2018-03-15T07:51:33.014Z")
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5aaa2606d52a86d42a36247a"),
            "created": ISODate("2018-03-13T07:51:34.702Z")
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5aaa262ad52a86d42a36247b"),
            "created": ISODate("2018-03-01T07:52:10.175Z")
        }
    ]
}
```